# why "pivot_wider" won't sum the value, but just listing each value as character

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to use  `pivot_wider` to summarize it to a wider format. The expected results will looks like this:

[image]

But my outcome looks like this:

[image]

Instead of adding each count, it put each `1` as character. What did I do wrong?

My sample data and the codes to build above table are:

```
df<-structure(list(Class = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), `Test date` = c(10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), Score = c("LOW", 
"LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "NORMAL", "HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH"
), Base_Score = c("LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"HIGH", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "NORMAL", "HIGH", "HIGH", "LOW", "NORMAL", "NORMAL", 
"NORMAL", "HIGH", "HIGH"), Number_student = c(44, 44, 44, 44, 
44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 
44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 
44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44), result = c("1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "NA", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>%
  mutate(result=as.numeric(df))%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Base_Score,
              values_from = result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need the `values_fn` to do the `sum`.  If there are duplicate elements, by default, the `pivot_wider` returns `list` columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(result = as.numeric(result)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Base_Score, 
        values_from = result, values_fn = list(result = sum))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Class `Test date` Score  Number_student   LOW NORMAL  HIGH
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A              10 LOW                44     4      2    NA
2 A              10 NORMAL             44     4     26     2
3 A              10 HIGH               44     1      3     2
```

Comment: Any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: @Stataq you meant without `pivot_wider`?

Comment: Yes. If we don't use `pivot_wider`, any other method?

Comment: @Stataq you can do a group by sum and then use pivot_wider i.e. `df %>% group_by(Class, `Test date`, Score, Base_Score, Number_student) %>% summarise(result = sum(as.numeric(result), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Base_Score, values_from = result)`

Comment: @Stataq you may use `dcast` i.e. `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(df), ... ~ Base_Score, value.var = 'result', function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))`

Comment: When I add `, values_fn = sum` to my old codes, I got `Error in values_fn[[value]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable`. any idea?

Comment: @Stataq it may be related to your version, try `values_fn = list(result = sum))`

Comment: Wonderful. How could you keep track of version updates. I find it very challenge.

Comment: @Stataq I had a similar issue earlier and I checked the usage which i remember when you mentioned this